I want to scale up the size of the points (already mapped) in my R animation using gganimate
p<-ggplot(gapminder,aes(gdpPercap,
             lifeExp,
             size = pop,
             color=continent))+
geom_point(alpha=0.5)+
scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 100)) # this is where its not working
scale_x_log10()+
theme_bw()+
labs(title = "year; {frame_time}",
     x= "GDP",
     y= "LE")+
transition_time(year)
animate(p, renderer = gifski_renderer())

I want to make the whole scale of the points larger so that it is easier to see, but I seem to be unable to do so. (sorry if i'm using the wrong terminology, i am new to R)
screenshot of output

This seems to work for me (though your code is missing the + at the end of the scale_size_continuous line):
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)


p <- ggplot(gapminder::gapminder,
            aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 100)) + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "year; {frame_time}", x = "GDP", y = "LE") +
  transition_time(year)

animate(p, renderer = gifski_renderer())


It might be perhaps that your new call isn't running and assigning the updated plot to p - animate would then render the non-modified object?

ah yes thank you, it was the last thing which fixed it. thank you so much!
